# Why does Rashi specifically tell us his interpretation method on 3:8?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, midrash, rashi, parashat-bereishit

In [Bereishis 3:8](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8167#v=8&showrashi=true), Rashi makes the following comment about his method of interpretation:

> וישמעו. יֵשׁ מִדְרְשֵׁי אַגָּדָה רַבִּים וּכְבָר סִדְּרוּם רַבּוֹתֵינוּ עַל מְכוֹנָם בִּבְ"רַ וּבִשְׁאָר מִדְרָשׁוֹת; וַאֲנִי לֹא בָאתִי אֶלָּא לִפְשׁוּטוֹ שֶׁל מִקְרָא וּלְאַגָּדָה הַמְיַשֶּׁבֶת דִּבְרֵי הַמִּקְרָא דָבָר דָּבוּר עַל אֳפַנָּיו:
>
> **And they heard:** There are many Aggadic midrashim, and our Sages already arranged them in their proper order in Genesis Rabbah and in
>   other midrashim, but I have come only [to teach] the simple meaning of
>   the Scripture and such Aggadah that clarifies the words of the verses,
>   each word in its proper way.

Why does he specifically comment on this *passuk*? Why not say this at the beginning of his commentary? What *prompts* Rashi to say this here?

Comment: He says this numerous times, when there is a great difference between famous midrashim an litteral lecture

Comment: Normally Rashi uses midrash. Since here he's not, he tells us.